# Doctrine entity field not recognized at all

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, entity-relationship

I am working with FOSUserBundle to authenticate. The authentication worked, so far so good. I have a couple of extra fields which populated nicely.

I then added a Roles-table (with the according entity), where the id-field is referenced by a roleid field in the database.

However, this field is not recognized by doctrine **at all**. Even

```
 php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

doesn't show it! Even when I rename my current table and then try to generate a create table-query, the field doesn't show up. I also tried renaming the field, but to no luck.

My field (in the class, of course):

```php
/*
 * @var int $roleid
 * 
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Roles")
 * @JoinColumn(name="roleid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $roleid;
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction of what is going on, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Shouldn´t it be @ORM\ManyToOne...  ?

Comment: Still nothing. Even when I try with a regular @ORM\Column annotation...

Comment: Can you post the whole code of your class?

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/VztL3a3W

Comment: You should also use @ORM\JoinColumn

Comment: It was the /** bit. I really never would've thought of that! Thanks so much :)

Comment: I added this as an answer so that you can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
/**
```

instead of

```
/*
```

otherwise the annotations will not be recognized

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the exact syntax

Use `/**` and not `/*`